# When page refresh, how to call back function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to maintain session after page refresh in angularjs using java. I have seen many examples but, i didn't find proper solution which exactly I'm looking for.
Please find below login snippet code, when i click on login button it is calling loginUser()function in LoginController 
When i do page refresh it is going to LoginController but it is not going inside loginUser()function.

According to my knowledge until we call function, it doesn't goes inside of it.
When I do refresh how can i call back loginUser() function.

please help me out from these. Appreciated..Many thanks.

**LoginController.js**

```
function LoginController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope,
    userService, SessionIdService) {
$scope.user = {};
$scope.user.username = '';
$scope.user.password = '';


$rootScope.loginUser = function(username, password) {

    $scope.resetError();

    $http.post('/user/main/login/' + username, password).success(
            function(login) {

                if (login.sessionId === null) {
                    $scope.setError(login.status);
                    return;
                } else {


                    $rootScope.userlogin = login.uname;
                    userService.setUserName(login.uname);
                    SessionIdService.setSessionId(login.sessionId);
                    $location.path("/home");
                }

            }).error(function() {
        $scope.setError('Invalid user/password combination');
    });

};

$scope.resetError = function() {
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.errorMessage = '';
};

$scope.setError = function(message) {
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.errorMessage = message;
    $rootScope.sees = '';
    $rootScope.userlogin = '';
};
```

};

**app.js**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, SessionIdService) {


$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

    console.log("Routechanged... ");

    if (SessionIdService.getSessionId == "true") {


        if (next.templateUrl == "scripts/views/homescreen.html") {
            $location.path("/home");

        } else {

            $location.path("/screen");
        }
    }
});
```

});

**login.html**

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" ng-model="user.username"/>   
<input name="textfield" type="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
<button type="button" ng-lick="loginUser(user.username,user.password)">Login</button>
```

Comment: Are you talking about refreshing the page after login is done or before. If it is before, user has to enter username\password again and click button again after refresh.

Comment: After login, on user home page when i refresh I'm unable to maintain user data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you want to call loginUser after page refresh. Isn't the user already logged in? I think what you want is to call the success function inside the loginIser. In that case, you need to embed that data as a global JS variable inside your Java template, and pass that to your controller somehow.

You probably want these to be run after refresh:

                    `$rootScope.userlogin = login.uname;
                    userService.setUserName(login.uname);
                    SessionIdService.setSessionId(login.sessionId);
                    $location.path("/home");`

So, in your Java template, do something like:

```
<script>window.UNAME = {% this comes from your database %};window.SESSIONID={% similar %}</script>
```

Then, call that function somehow with window.UNAME as input. (or in your controller, check  for the existence of window.UNAME and call it immediately. Something like:

```
window.UNAME && function (name, sessionId) {
                    $rootScope.userlogin = uname;
                    userService.setUserName(uname);
                    SessionIdService.setSessionId(sessionId);
                    $location.path("/home");
) {

}(window.UNAME, window.SESSION_ID)
```

Some other recommendations (unrelated to your main problem probably):

First of, change `$rootScope.loginUser = function(username, password) {` to

`$rootScope.loginUser = function() {
var username = $scope.user.username;
var password = $scope.user.password`

since you already have access to username and password there. So, change `ng-click="loginUser()"`.

Second, SessionIdService.getSessionId == "true" seems off, check should probably be just  SessionIdService.getSessionId

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here, when user suppose to click on refresh,it is calling controller but i'm unable to go inside function. I want to recall that function. I followed below example,in that part2 is not working for me as expected. 
http://blog.e-bluesoft.com/angularjs-login-dialog-with-springmvc-part-1/

Comment: Issue solved, I'm able to recall the function and maintain session. Thanks for all your replies.